# laravel запрос в бд

Tags: laravel

```
public function index()
{
    $users = DB::table('oc_product')->get();
    $data['title'] = "test";
    return view('users',$data);
}
```

}

Выдает ошибку SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'laravel.oc_product' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `oc_product`)
Как исправить? Всем спасибо.

Comment: Проинициализировать базу данных. То место, откуда вы взяли этот код, должно подсказать, как это сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Укажите название вашей базы данных в app/config/database.php

```
'default' => 'nameDB'
```

Comment: другие запросы работают? может вы неправильно подключили БД

Answer (score 0):

БД подключена верно, ошибка говорит что в **схеме laravel** не найдена таблица или представление oc_product, скорее всего проста опечатка в названии:)